# Android: how to know what is the minimum required API to run my Android app?

Tags: android, eclipse, api, target

As everybody, I use in my project many libraries and methods. For each method, it is mentioned "Available since API XX" in the Android documentation.

Is there a tool in Ecplise to know what is the minimum API required to run my project ? (without having to go throw all the methods used in my project to check which one uses the lowest API...)

A solution is to use the emulator with different levels of API but is there any other simple tool to do this checking ?

I use Eclipse.

Thanks !

[EDIT]

Found the solution ! What I actually did is the following (very simple):
1) Right click on your project folder (blue folder)
2) Click "Properties"
3) Click "Android"
4) Decrease the API version
5) Click on "Apply" and "OK"
6) See if some errors appears
6) Repeat the procedure until finding the lowest API for which one you don't have errors
7) Write the API level in targetSdkVersion in your AndroidManifest.xml !! 
8) Finally, test the app in the emulator set up with this minimum API level !

Comment: Well it is always good to start project with minimal expected/safely runnable SDK you want to support, instead of trying to down-grade

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decrease the value of`targetSdkVersion` in your `AndroidManifest.xml`, and keep decreasing it until you start to get errors or warnings.